# ReactJS unit test case using react-testing-library and jest when Promise is reject

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-testing-library

I am new to React and react-testing-library. I have below component and I am facing problem in writing unit test case when Promise is rejected in service call:

```
const Hotels = () => {

const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    ServiceComponent.get('http://example.com').then((response)=>{
        setNames(response?.['names']?? null);
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.error(err);
    });
}, []);


return(
   <Names names={names}/>
)
}

export default Hotels;
```

I am able to mock ServiceComponent and test the successful Promise. But, I am not able to write test case for the catch block:

```
catch(err =>{
        console.error(err);
    })
```

I have tried using

```
ServiceComponent.get.mockRejectedValue(new Error("error"));
```

but it also did not help.

I am new to react and its test cases.

Answer (score 0):

there is one way you can test the catch block by creating a `mock function` that throws an error since in the catch block you are not showing any errors to the UI like a pop-up/modal which shows that some error has occurred, you will have to pass a mock function which will get triggered when the catch block is called, and you can verify if the catch block is called by checking if the mock function is triggered or not

```
import { get } from './service';
jest.mock('./service')

describe("<App />", () => {

  it("check if catch function is called",() => {
    const mockError = jest.fn();
    get.mockImplementation(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mockError();
        throw new Error("its a error");
      })
    })
    render(<App />);
    expect(mockError).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```